# Python convert mix from UTF-16 and UTF-8(?) to regular string

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

I have bytes (from requests.get) like this:

```
<th class=\"app_result_head\">\u0414\u043e\u043b\u0436\u043d\u0438\u043a<\/th>
```

How do I convert this to proper python string like this?:

```
<th class="app_result_head">Должник</th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my_bytes - 'bytes' in question. As it turns out answer is rather simple.

```
out = my_bytes.decode('raw_unicode_escape')
out = out.replace('\"', '"')
out = out.replace('\/', "/")
```

From docs for raw_unicode_escape:

```
Latin-1 encoding with \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX for other code points.
```

This is exactly what I've needed

Comment: this is python 2 only right? python 3 str has no attribute `decode`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this 3.5.2. my_bytes is not string, it's 'bytes' type. I'll edit answer

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i got bytes from requests.get(), it returns bytes, not string

Comment: You can use normal `unicode-escape` to take care of other backslash escapes, instead of doing it manually and incompletely. However, in any case it seems pretty unlikely that a scraped web page would contain Python-format string literals. Are you sure you haven't got something else like JSON? If so you should use a proper JSON parser. There are *many* formats that use `\u` escapes and they have different edge-case rules.